# error: could not convert operator from fraction to bool

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
#include "fraction.h"

int main()
{
    Fraction f(1,2);
    Fraction g(1,2);

     if (f > g)  cout << f << " > " << g << endl;

    return 0;
 }
```

---

```
Fraction::Fraction()
{
    //ctor
    m_top = 0;
    m_bottom = 1;
}

Fraction::Fraction(int t, int b)
{
    //ctor
    m_top = t;
    m_bottom = b;
    reduce();
}

bool Fraction operator>(const Fraction& l, const Fraction& r)
{
    int a = l.getTop();
    int b = l.getBottom();
    int c = r.getTop();
    int d = r.getBottom();
    if ((a*d-c*b) > (b*d))

    return true;
}

void Fraction::reduce()
{
    int g=gcf(m_top, m_bottom);
    m_top /= g;
    m_bottom /= g;
}

/// recursive
int Fraction::gcf(int m, int n)
{
    if (n == 0) return m;
    return gcf(n, m % n);
}
```

---

```
#ifndef FRACTION_H
#define FRACTION_H

#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Fraction
{

    public:
        Fraction();
        Fraction(int, int);
        int getTop() {return m_top;}
        int getBottom() {return m_bottom;}
        void set(int t, int b) {m_top=t; m_bottom=b; reduce();}
        Fraction( Fraction t, Fraction b);
    protected:
    private:
        void reduce();
        int gcf(int, int);

        int m_top;
        int m_bottom;



};

ostream& operator<<(ostream&, Fraction);
Fraction operator+(Fraction l, Fraction r);
Fraction operator*(Fraction l, Fraction r);
Fraction operator/(Fraction l, Fraction r);
Fraction operator>(Fraction l, Fraction r);
Fraction operator>=(Fraction l, Fraction r);
Fraction operator<(Fraction l, Fraction r);
Fraction operator<=(Fraction l, Fraction r);
Fraction operator==(Fraction l, Fraction r);
Fraction operator!=(Fraction l, Fraction r);


#endif // FRACTION_H
```

The log says error occurs on int main()
error: could not convert 'operator>(f,g)' from 'Fraction' to 'bool'

Can someone tell me what im doing wrong, and fix my code?
Is the problem with the bool statement? if so how can I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

```
Fraction operator>(Fraction l, Fraction r);
Fraction operator>=(Fraction l, Fraction r);
Fraction operator<(Fraction l, Fraction r);
Fraction operator<=(Fraction l, Fraction r);
Fraction operator==(Fraction l, Fraction r);
Fraction operator!=(Fraction l, Fraction r);
```

These operators should return **boolean**, not `Fraction`:

```
bool operator>(Fraction l, Fraction r);
bool operator>=(Fraction l, Fraction r);
bool operator<(Fraction l, Fraction r);
bool operator<=(Fraction l, Fraction r);
bool operator==(Fraction l, Fraction r);
bool operator!=(Fraction l, Fraction r);
```

The compiler tells you that is cannot convert the return value `Fraction` to `bool` as it is expected from these kind of operators.

**EDIT**

Moreover, the expected signature for these operators is:

```
bool operator>(const Fraction& l, const Fraction& r);
bool operator>=(const Fraction& l, const Fraction& r);
bool operator<(const Fraction& l, const Fraction& r);
bool operator<=(const Fraction& l, const Fraction& r);
bool operator==(const Fraction& l, const Fraction& r);
bool operator!=(const Fraction& l, const Fraction& r);
```

**`const`** because these operators should not modify the input values and reference **`&`** is in order to avoid copying the whole object.